# Dozer Mapping - Map elements to child class instead of parent class

Tags: java, dozer

I have base class orderItem and have child classes DeviceItem and ServiceItem. I have provided the definition below. When I get this request I perform dozer mapping to translate this for jaxb model to another data model that I have created. My data model also has same OrderItem , DerviceItem and DeviceItem classes which are POJOs. When I do a dozer mapping , the classes get mapped to OrderItem (base class) instead of specialized child classes. Is there a way to perform this user dozer mapping?

```
<ns2:orderItem xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type = "ns2:ServiceItem">
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this following the steps in this [link](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/baseattributes.html) by providing hints.